# Autocovariance equal to variance

Tags: covariance, variance

I guess it is a stupid question with an easy answer, namely: no. But I have discussed with someone claiming it's possible, so I am confused.

Consider a vector of random variables $(X_1, X_2, ..., X_n)$, each coming from the same distribution (if anyone is familiar with the process time models - it's process time model A).

Is it possible that the autocovariance function equal variance? In other words, I was told to consider the situation that autocovariance is constant and equal to variance.

Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Assume that it is, and calculate the correlation coefficient for any two samples, say $X_s,X_t$.

Comment: I obtain 1 but I can't really imagine such process. I mean, results of my considerations are not logical in that case, unlike for a white noice process.

Comment: What consideration do you find not logical?  Or rather, what does a correlation of 1 mean about each subsequent iteration of process?

Comment: That there exists a linear relationship between them. But if we have each step of a process having the same expectation value, how could the values decrease (increase). The process would have to be constant. But it's not the same as "each step coming from the same distribution".

Comment: Exactly.  So...?

Comment: So it's only the case for processes where only one value is possible and for others the probability is zero?